# Does an individual's profiler output have any effect on gameplay?

Tags: watch-dogs

While profiling people you'll occasionally come across one that is reported to have a problem that should affect their abilities in the game world, for example:

[image]

Does an individual's profiler output have any effect on gameplay or is all of this stuff strictly flavour text only?

Comment: Just a note: the average person has blind spots in both eyes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's all just flavour text. Sometimes on missions it helps you find your target, although the target, once profiled, will be marked either way.